# matplotlib show window as the active one

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting some graphs and then I interact with them using the `canvas.mpl_connect` commands. So when I show the plot, I want the window to be the active one since the beginning.

At the moment, when the script is run, the plot pops up but it's not the active window, the terminal still is (i.e. if I type a key, that is written in the Terminal, and not interpreted by the plot-window). I need to click on the plot-window to make it the active one and then I'm able to interact with the graphs. It would be way nicer if it was already active the first time it pops up.

Working on MacOSX 10.10.3 with python 2.7.5 and matplotlib 1.3.1

EDIT

I don't just need to bring the window in front, I want to be able to interact with the window without having to click on it. So if I type some keys, the graph will respond and not the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the order windows are displayed in using canvas manager but it only works with some graphical backends. The following example uses the TkAgg backend which works but the same idea won't work the macosx backend.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pylab import get_current_fig_manager

fig1 = plt.figure()
fig2 = plt.figure()

fig1.canvas.manager.window.attributes('-topmost', 1)

plt.show()
```

Figure 1 should show up on top of figure 2.

Comment: That will just bring the window to front but it won't make it active.

Comment: Ah. In that case I don't know. Once you make this the top figure you can use command-tab to make it active but I don't know how to make it any more automated.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've finally found a solution here https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/663

Apparently a work around is to import

`from AppKit import NSApplication`

and issuing just before `show()`:

`NSApplication.sharedApplication().activateIgnoringOtherApps_(True)`

I'm not really sure what it does, and apparently it works just in non-interactive mode, but that worked perfectly for me.

You might also want to check here
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/665/